# SQL Update with CASE

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

could you please help me with this SQL?

```
UPDATE VERSION
SET VERSION_STATUS_ID = IF((SELECT COUNT(*) from VERSION where KEY = 'ABC') > 1, 5, 6)
WHERE VERSION_ID = 1;
```

Error report -

> SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"

Thanks

Comment: use a case statement

Comment: @Ryan as Jarlh will tell you, it's actually a `CASE` _expression_.

Comment: CASE is your friend because it is standard SQL and works in pretty much every database: http://modern-sql.com/feature/case

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE VERSION
SET VERSION_STATUS_ID = CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) from VERSION where KEY = 'ABC') > 1
                             THEN 5 ELSE 6 END
WHERE VERSION_ID = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` is usually more efficient than `COUNT(*)` in a subquery.  If you have a unique id column in the table, you can use:

```
UPDATE VERSION v
    SET VERSION_STATUS_ID = (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                                               FROM VERSION v2
                                               WHERE v2.KEY = 'ABC' AND
                                                     v2.VERSION_ID <> v.VERSION_ID
                                              ) > 1
                                  THEN 5 ELSE 6
                             END)
WHERE VERSION_ID = 1;
```

This assumes that `VERSION_ID` is unique.  If you don't have such an explicitly declared column, you can use `ROWID` instead.

Answer (score 0):

### try this is working very good

```
  SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
 EXPE NUMBER;
 SAL NUMBER;
BEGIN


 SELECT TRUNC((SYSDATE - hire_date) / 365)  INTO EXPE
 FROM EMPLOYEES 
 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 155;   


 UPDATE  EMPLOYEES 
 SET SALARY = CASE 
 WHEN   EXPE > 15 THEN SALARY+(SALARY*20/100)
 WHEN   EXPE < 15 THEN SALARY+(SALARY*30/100)
 ELSE 0
 END;

 SELECT SALARY INTO SAL
 FROM EMPLOYEES 
 WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID =155;

 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('THIS IS THE SALARY ' || '  ' ||SAL || ' ' || ' AND THIS IS THE EXPERINCE '||EXPE);
END;
```